# std vector performance/alternative

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I have to process and store data temporarily. Currently I use `std::vector::push_back` to add data and `std::vector::erase` to erase elements when max elements is reached. My problem is that I have to process a lot of data and that when the max amount is reached, erasing seems to hit performance. So I decided to add data and erase x elements every y ms, as an optimization. To start, I also reserve a certain amount in the vector. I use a vector because I need the `const double *std::vector<T>::data()` function to pass the data to somewhere else and I can't have any conversion/copying or anything. It just has to be fast.

```
std::vector<double> data;
size_t max; // there are millions of elements, e.g. 2000000
data.reserve(max);

// happens every x microseconds
void receive(double val) {
    data.push_back(val);
}

// timed every x ms
void update() {
    if (data.size() > max)
        data.erase(data.begin(),data.end()+(data.size()-max));
}
```

My question is: How can I make this more efficient? By using another container? Is it then still possible to convert the container to a `const double *`?

I realize just now that I always exceed max with this setup, could that be the reason for the performance drop? Would the following code fix the issue?

```
if (data.size() > max*0.8)
        data.erase(data.begin(),data.begin()+(data.size()-max*0.8));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Look at `std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: I did but it has no const T *data() function, or does it?

Comment: A circular buffer might also be a solution.

Comment: No, `deque` is not contiguous data.

Comment: In a circular buffer, positions remain the same. I need the whole vector to shift.

Comment: Can't you just shift your read/write position instead of shifting every element?

Comment: @Ceros I guess that might be a good idea.

Comment: `data.erase(data.begin(),data.end()+(data.size()-max));` this doesn't look safe. Perhaps you meant for both iterators to be `data.begin()`?

Comment: @AndyG right :) typo

Comment: If you are able to use external libraries then [plf::colony](http://plflib.org/colony.htm) might be worth a look. I think it was created exactly for this purpose. The author did a [cppcon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBER1R8YyGY) on it as well. Although I just saw it was unordered, so I dont know if thats an issue.

Comment: @Paul Rooney, I can only use boost, sadly nothing else available and I can't just install something.

Comment: Your requirements have boxed you into a corner. For contiguous data, you need to occasionally move data around.

Comment: In what fashion the data is processed _somewhere else_? Is it possible to allocate, say, a new `vector` each time the processor is called?

Comment: @AsetD The pointer is used somewhere else to parse the data. So allocating a new vector would only make a new memory block and destroy the data of which the pointer is passed, resulting in undefined behavior I guess.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is it possible to move the whole vector efficiently one pos? Like data[0] = data[1]; data[1] = data.begin(); ?

Comment: It's actually more efficient to move the vector multiple positions at once. `erase` the way you're using it should be the best you can do. And to expand on what @AsetD is asking, would it be possible to use *multiple* buffers? Does each call to the processor require all the data that was already passed to a previous call?

Comment: @MarkRansom "Multiple" buffers without destroying them, that might actually be a good solution, didn't think of that.

Comment: @MarkRansom But I still don't see how multiple vectors could improve performance in this case.

Comment: @MarkRansom The pointer is passed and the data is processed somewhere else, so the vector can not be destroyed. And all the data has to be passed all the time.

Comment: It seems you are asking for the impossible... if your requirements are that you have a single flat buffer, then there is no way to erase from the middle without shifting down all the elements above, which will take time

Comment: This just feels like you're abusing vector when you really want some other container, like a queue. What do you need this container to *do*? Not how do you want to do it, just what it needs to do.

Comment: @MarkRansom and to copy is not an option, there is too much and it has to be processed in 50 milliseconds max.

Comment: @fonZ (Pedantic mode on) You know most system are not realtime? You can't guarantee "max X ms"

Comment: @GManNickG It has to collect data, with a size limit, and serve the most recent data as const double *.

Comment: @M.M I was feeling the same but it was worth a try to ask. But, I guess it takes more time to erase 10 times 10 elements than to erase 100 at once? Or am I wrong? Because if so, I will just periodically clean it up and reserve more space.

Comment: I'd expect it takes longer to copy data around 10 times than to copy it around once

Comment: Are you guaranteed to only serve the data once?  You can keep multiple vectors, and once update is called start writing to a new vector, for example.

Comment: @GManNickG lets say I have a size 3 vector, then I would serve: 1 then 1,2  then 1,2,3 then 2,3,4 then, 3,4,5 etc. So I add one at the end and remove one at the beginning once max (3) is reached.

Comment: Well, thanks all for helping me think. Any suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, your requirements really have you boxed in. The only container I'm aware of that gives you contiguous data is `std::vector`.

There are two time-wasters associated with `std::vector`. The first is when you try to `push_back` on a vector that is already at its reserved capacity; a new buffer must be allocated, and the old buffer contents copied to the new buffer. You can avoid this easily by erasing elements before you reach the capacity. The second is erasing from anywhere other than the end of the vector; this necessitates copying elements from their old location in the buffer to their new location. *This part is unavoidable*. Your only choice is to do this as infrequently as possible, erasing as many elements at once as you can.

Here's a mod that gives you both conditions:

```
void receive(double val) {
    static const size_t drop_size = max / 2;
    if (data.size() == data.capacity()) {
        data.erase(data.begin(), data.begin() + drop_size);
    }
    data.push_back(val);
}
```

This drops a portion of the data whenever the buffer becomes full. I've arbitrarily chosen max/2, but you can adjust that threshold to meet your actual requirements.

A good compiler will optimize the copying of elements during `erase`, but there's a slight possibility that you could do better yourself with `memcpy`. In that case you can replace the `erase` with the following:

```
memcpy(&(data[0]), &(data[drop_size]), sizeof(double) * (data.size() - drop_size));
data.resize(data.size() - drop_size);
```

You should definitely benchmark this before you decide to go with it. <strike>I'm not aware of any `vector` implementations that will reduce the capacity of a vector when you resize it, but I don't think that's a requirement of the standard.</strike> Edit: the standard includes a requirement that iterators won't be invalidated when you resize below the current capacity, which guarantees that the capacity *will not* be reduced.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll give it a try.